# How to get item from ItemsSource for double clicked TreeViewItem's child TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a `TreeView` with `TreeViewItems`, which `ItemsSource` is `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`

```
var myList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(); 
TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
TreeViewItem treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem {
    Header = headerStackPanel,
    ItemsSource = myList 
};
treeView.Items.Add(treeViewItem);
```

How can I get object of `MyClass` when double clicking on corresponding `TextBlock`? Only thing that I've done is getting `MyClass.ToString()`, which stores in `TextBlock.Text`:

```
treeViewItem.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) => {
    TextBlock tb = args.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
    if (tb == null) {
         return; 
    }
    string myClassToString = tb.Text;
};
```

Also: not from XAML, from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the `SelectedItem` of TreeView into `MyClass`:

```
treeViewItem.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) => {
    if (yourTreeView.SelectedItem is MyClass) {
        var myClass = yourTreeView.SelectedItem as MyClass;
        //Do something with myClass.
    }
    //Additionally in this aproach you can
    //check if selected item is TreeViewItem and get e.g. Header property.
    else if (yourTreeView.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem) {
        var treeViewItem = yourTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        string header = treeViewItem.Header;
    }       
};
```

or use `DataContext` property of `TextBlock` in the same way:

```
treeViewItem.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) => {
   TextBlock tb = args.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
   if (tb == null) {
       return; 
   }
   else if (tb.DataContext is MyClass) {
       var myClass = tb.DataContext as MyClass;
       //Do something with myClass   
   }      
};
```

Comment: Although this might be a good answer, please consider adding some more explanation about why this is the right solution and what exactly you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DataContext of your TextBlock.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand how silly my question is.